# Oracle ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row, but actually no rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I can already hear the groans looking at my title but please bear with me a moment. :)

I have two tables that have a few columns in common and are updated through different means. Given a specific identifier I want to update the first table with values from the second table if the first table is missing some information.

Table A looks something like:

```
Dept_ID  Reviewer  Reviewer_Team  Reviewer_Code
ACM      Null      Null           Null
EOT      Null      Null           Null
QQQ      Joe       Joe's Group    XYZ
ACM      Null      Null           Null
ZZZ      Null      Null           Null
```

Table B looks something like:

```
Dept_ID  Reviewer  Reviewer_Team  Reviewer_Code
AAA      Al        Al's Group     123
BBB      Bob       Bob's Group    234
ZZZ      Zoe       Zoe's Group    567
```

If Reviewer_Code is Null in Table A we want to find Table A's Dept_ID in Table B, and update Table A's other fields to match Table B. Note that Table A might have multiple records with the same Dept_ID in which case we'd expect them to have the same values updated from Table B.

Sounds easy. Using the above tables as an example there are no matches in Table B, so the ACM and EOT records would not be updated at this step. Table A's ZZZ record though would get updated based on Table B's ZZZ record.

However there's a chance that there would be no matches in Table B. So pretend Table A doesn't have the ZZZ record, just the ACM and EOT that have Nulls.

I'm new to Oracle (coming from SQL Server) so maybe I'm testing this wrong, but what I have is a bunch of queries one after another in a .sql window of Oracle SQL Developer. This seems to work for me just fine normally. When it gets to this query though I get the dreaded "single-row subquery" error.

Here's the query I've tried a few different ways:

```
UPDATE VchrImpDetailCombined vchr
SET (Reviewer, Reviewer_Team, Reviewer_Code) =
  (SELECT DISTINCT b.Reviewer, b.Reviewer_Team, b.Reviewer_Code
   FROM GlobPMSDeptIdMapping b 
   WHERE b.Dept_Id = vchr.Dept_Id)
   WHERE vchr.Reviewer_Code IS NULL
     AND vchr.Business_L1 = 'CF'
     AND vchr.Dept_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
UPDATE VchrImpDetailCombined vchr
SET (Reviewer, Reviewer_Team, Reviewer_Code) =
  (SELECT DISTINCT b.Reviewer, b.Reviewer_Team, b.Reviewer_Code
   FROM GlobPMSDeptIdMapping b 
   inner join VchrImpDetailCombined a
   on b.Dept_Id = a.Dept_Id
   WHERE b.Dept_Id = vchr.Dept_Id)
   WHERE vchr.Reviewer_Code IS NULL
     AND vchr.Business_L1 = 'CF'
     AND vchr.Dept_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

I've tried a few other things as well such as doing "WHERE EXISTS SELECT blahblah", or "WHERE b.Dept_ID IS NOT NULL", etc.

Now, given my example data above, the subquery should have 0 records, keeping in mind there actually isn't a ZZZ record in Table A like my example, just the ACM and EOT. Table B simply doesn't have records with the matching Dept_ID in Table A. So my expectation would be for a 0 record update and happily moving along to the next query.

When I run these queries in a string of other queries I get the error. If I run the query all by its lonesome I simply get a "3 rows updated" which seems odd that anything is updating considering there should be no matches. But the 3 rows updated would seem to match the 3 ACM and EOT records even though Table B has nothing to update from given the criteria.

I must be missing something obvious, but I just can't seem to grasp it. There's a bajillion of these ORA-01427 questions so I was so sure I could find the answer already out there, but couldn't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing I notice is the `SELECT DISTINCT`, which is unlikely to do what you want.  You do not need it if there is a uniqueness constraint on `GlobPMSDeptIdMapping.Reviewer_Code` (including if it is the primary key), and otherwise it is not guaranteed to reduce the subquery results to a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct Oracle that it should perform the update only when there are data with which to do so (and I would have expected such to be needed for SQL Server as well, but I'm uncertain).  This will overcome that obstacle, at the expense of performing an additional subquery:

```
UPDATE VchrImpDetailCombined vchr
SET (Reviewer, Reviewer_Team, Reviewer_Code) = (
  SELECT b.Reviewer, b.Reviewer_Team, b.Reviewer_Code
   FROM GlobPMSDeptIdMapping b 
   WHERE b.Dept_Id = vchr.Dept_Id
)
WHERE vchr.Reviewer_Code IS NULL
  AND vchr.Business_L1 = 'CF'
  AND vchr.Dept_ID IN (
    SELECT Dept_Id
    FROM GlobPMSDeptIdMapping
  );
```

Per my comment on the question, I removed the `DISTINCT` from the (original) subquery, as it's either unneeded or ineffective.